# Developing two Nuget packages at the same time

Tags: c#, nuget, project, nuget-package-restore

Suppose project `A 1.0` depends on `B 1.0` (each is it's own nuget package). I get these projects from source control, so after package restore `A 1.0` has a dll reference to `B 1.0`.

I want to develop `A` and `B` at the same time, and publish to Nuget with `A 2.0` depending on `B 2.0`.

How can I do this?

**Note:** I cant simply add `A` and `B` to a solution because `A` will still have a dll reference, and wont be updated when `B` updates. Also manually changing the dll reference to a project reference and changing it back before publishing seems laborious (especially with more projects).

**Edit:** I don't want to publish to the Nuget server until `A` and `B` have been fully developed to v2.

Comment: A might not update exactly when B updates, but surly when you are developing A 2.0 you  have a |B 2.0 dependency - so you can get a dll reference (or rather the A project has a nuget package requirement of B 2.0)

Comment: @Batavia Only if you publish B to the Nuget server and A does a package restore on build. But I don't want to publish A and B until both have been developed (I edited the question to add this).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do when developing nuget packages is using a fileshare as your own nuget server. you can look here https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds how to make a feed from your local file system

Then you make sure that the build of B produces a nuget package, and put it in your own c:\devenvironment\nugetsnapshot directory.

After that you can just look at that directory for your nuget packages and you can develop A against a snapshot for B without publishing it.

Alternatively you could create your own development nuget server or mark snapshots as prerepeases so people know they might be broken

Comment: Will this require something to sync my local Nuget folder with the Nuget server? E.g. A also depends on C but C isn't in my local Nuget folder.